# Getting distance meter value between two geometries in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, distance

I am using PostGIS.

I would like to get the distance between two geometries. I am using this sid : 4269 in meters
what i am doing now is this : `ST_Distance((a.geom,b.geom)) FROM ...` but I am getting result in degrees.

I think that I should work with geography but how can I cast a geom to a geography?

I tried with (a.geom::geography) but i am getting an error.

What can I do to get my result in meters?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

with [ST_Distance_Sphere](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) you can achieve that:

```
ST_Distance_Sphere(a.geom,b.geom)
```

Answer (score 4):

The units of SRID 4269 ([NAD 83](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum)) are not metres - this is a [geodetic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_reference_system#Geodetic_coordinates), i.e. the co-ordinates are degrees (geographic co-ordinates).

pacofvf's answer will give you the distance in metres, but if you really did have your intial co-ordinates specified in metres then then you should use a projected co-ordinate system. Probably for North America you want something like [State Plane Coordinate System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Plane_Coordinate_System) which has a number of different projections depending on which region you want to map.

I suspect though that you are just using lat/lon values so probably this second paragraph isn't relevant - just use the `ST_Distance_Sphere` function as above.